PyQt5 Seg fault when trying to access pyqtBoundSignal
Whenever I try to access a variable set to pyqtBoundSignal(), I get a seg fault.
Here's the code:
from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    Qt,
    pyqtBoundSignal
)

class Controls(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.file_selected = pyqtBoundSignal()
        print(self.file_selected)

I tried to look it up, but nobody seems to have the same issue. I tried using pyqtSignal instead, but it doesn't have the connect, disconnect and emit methods.

pyqtBoundSignal is not intended for public use, it's internally created by a standard unbound (pyqtSignal) signal when an instance of a QObject class is created. Signals must always be declared at class level, you cannot create signals for instances. You probably want to create some "dynamic" signal, which is not possible. The only possibility is to create dynamic classes that can eventually declare signals when their instances are created, but not after.
